# ABI::Windows::UI::Input::IGestureRecognizer issue

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winapi, abi

Good day everyone!

I'm developing a wpf application, that has it's main logic implemented in a C++\CLI library.

First of all, I have to say, that I'm new to WPF as I develop UWP applications.

And here is my issue:
I have created an `ABI::Windows::UI::Input::IGestureRecognizer`. And my stumbling block is calling `ABI::Windows::UI::Input::IGestureRecognizer::ProcessXXXEvent` methods.

Since I am developing a WPF application, I can not get an `ABI::Windows::UI::Core::ICoreWindow` instance, so I can not subscribe to it's events and retrieve argument i should pass into `ABI::Windows::UI::Input::IGestureRecognizer::ProcessXXXEvent`.

So at this point, I am asking you, if there is any workaround in my situation or am I lacking an understanding in what I am doing or should I just change my approach to what I am doing.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Sounds like you are using C++/CX, but the question is tagged [tag:c++] and [tag:c#]. What language are you using? Also, the term *"C++\CLR library"* is unknown to me. Are you referring to a mixed-mode assembly written in C++/CLI? And how does that relate to your (unmanaged, probably) implementation of a Windows Runtime type?

Comment: I ment C++\CLI when i typed C++\CLR( Thank you for spotting the mistake

Comment: With WPF you don't want to use UWP classes; instead, you want to use WPF classes, which are all in `System::Windows` (but not `System::Windows::Forms`). For input, you want [`System::Windows::Input`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input(v=vs.110).aspx).